# Box and diamond proprierties in Propositional Dynamic Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I read that, while ⟨a⟩B implies that the program "a" will eventually come to an end, [a]B does not imply the same thing. Would anyone care to explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Stanford Encyclopedia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dynamic/#Int):

> [$\dots$] If $\alpha$ is a program and $A$ is a formula then $[\alpha]A$ (“every execution of $\alpha$ from the present state leads to a state where $A$ is true”) is a formula.
>
> [$\dots$]  In addition, we abbreviate $\neg [\alpha]\neg A$ to $\langle \alpha \rangle A$ (“some execution of $\alpha$ from the present state leads to a state where $A$ is true”) as in modal logic.

With this in mind, $\langle a \rangle B$ means that there *does exist* an execution of $a$, and that execution will lead to $B$ being true.
However, $[a]B$ simply means that *if* there is an execution of $a$, then $B$ will be true, but we do not know whether such an execution exists or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful explanation!

Comment: @MattB in that case, an upvote and/or an accept would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't yet, mate. I still have less than 15 reps.